# Call SOAP/Web Service from within MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, web-services, soap

I'm new to the world of SOAP/Web Services and am wondering if it is possible to call the API from within MySQL or MSSQL in a stored procedure or job or something?  Ideally I want to automate pulling a list of numbers from a database table, then send those numbers to an API.  After I get a result, parse and input results into the database.

I've worked with API's before but more from a PHP side of things where a user actually clicks a button that kicks off a function or whatever.  This I want to run in the background do all that the updating as needed.  Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: MySQL and MSSQL are very different in how they will approach this.  In MSSQL you can use SSIS and schedule a task to do this. With MySQL you will need to look at a ETL Tool. Calling a web-service from within a stored procedure can be done but is not always a good idea.

Comment: Thanks Namphibian, will look into it.  I'm really interested in making this work the right way.